# How to find slice object in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, find, slice

I have a numpy array containing integers and slice objects, e.g.:

```
x = np.array([0,slice(None)])
```

How do I retrieve the (logical) indices of the integers or slice objects? I tried `np.isfinite(x)` (producing an error), `np.isreal(x)` (all `True`),  `np.isscalar(x)` (not element-wise), all in vain.
What seems to work though is

```
ind = x<np.Inf       # Out[1]: array([True, False], dtype=bool)
```

but I'm reluctant to use a numerical comparison on an object who's numerical value is completely arbitrary (and might change in the future?). Is there a better solution to achieve this?

Comment: All items in a numpy array share a same `dtype`. If you look at `x.dtype` you will see that it is `dtype('object')`. So from a vectorized type checking point of view, they are all the same. Do you really need to mix different things in the same array? It is probably easier to refactor your code a little to take advantage of numpy, than to make numpy work the way you are doing.

Comment: @Jaime Actually, the data is stored as a list: `[0,slice(None)]`; from this list I can retrieve the slice objects (or the indices of those) using a list comprehension, but I thought it would be quicker to (mis)use a numpy array for that purpose. Indeed, this is 4 times faster than a list comprehension, if it weren't for the fact that the conversion from list to array is 10 times slower ... :-( So, problem solved/evaded: better use a list comprehension. For multiple selections in the same list, though, the array method may still pay off. Anyway, thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
import numpy as np
checker = np.vectorize( lambda x: isinstance(x,slice) )
x = np.array([0,slice(None),slice(None),0,0,slice(None)])
checker(x)
#array([False,  True,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```